# IFormFile not being populated by dropzone uploadMultiple request

Tags: c#, http, file-upload, .net-core, dropzone.js

The problem I am having is that the List of IFormFile is not being populated with the given files but when i call HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; then I have access to the files. I would prefer to use IFormFile as it seems to be new Dotnet core 2.0 way of doing things.

I have the following request payload:
[image: request payload]

With the following request headers: 
[image: request headers]

And Razor pages handler:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostSend(ConditionResponse conditionResponse)
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    }
```

Condition response model:

```
public class ConditionResponse
{
    public List<string> Plots { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi , I am having the same issue. Can you please paste your entire code here

Comment: You should not need the entire code. The answer below shows how in the JS you just need to use the paramName option. Be sure you are naming the IFormFile the same as the string returned from myParamName.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking at the request from a html5 multiple file upload I noticed the request does not add the indexes to the filename (files[n]). Dropzone.js does this so there is a work around. If you add the paramName option to Dropzone JS config and have it call a method which returns files you will get the same behaviour as the html5 multiple file upload.

```
function myParamName() {
                return "files";
            }

 Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                uploadMultiple: true,
                paramName: myParamName,
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Could you explain why does this work? and how did you discovered it?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've been trying to get it to work for a while now! This should really be added to the Dropzone docs

Comment: @m.brookson no problem, if the answer worked for you could you give an upvote please

Comment: @m.brookson no problem, if the answer worked for you cand if you believe the question is useful then could you also upvote these, thanks

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer worked perfectly, I am not sure why and how, but it works. I just wanted to get rid of that additional function, i.e., we can use it like this:

```
 Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                uploadMultiple: true,
                paramName: () => "files",
}
```

Or if old browsers are also targeted:

```
 Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                uploadMultiple: true,
                paramName: function () { "files" },
}
```

Comment: Yes great suggestion. Worth mentioning this will only work with es6 compatible browser versions.

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen, do you have any explanation why does this work?

Comment: When DropzoneJs sends the reuqest it adds an index to each file for example files[0], files[1], files[2] where as the IFormFile expects the exact same name for files for example files, files, files

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen, yes, I just meant why passing a reference to a function works?