# POST actions in [ApiController] in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following ASP.NET Core 2.1 Api controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImagesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm]ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    { ... }

    [HttpGet("thumbnails")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetThumbNails()
    { ... }
```

Both the GET and POST actions worked with Postman.

However, the POST action would not work with the UI: the action would always receive a files parameter count of 0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910000/why-is-iformfile-collection-empty-when-sent-from-dropzone-js) for full details of the fault).

I eventually fixed the fault by removing the `[ApiController]` attribute from the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class ImagesController : ControllerBase
{ ... }
```

My question is why did the `[ApiController]` controller attribute prevent the POST method from receiving the files from the UI?  What is happening here?  Is it a routing problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the compatibility version:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Aha np :) I had almost the same issue today, so I found your question. Adding this fixed it for me. Maybe it will help other people.

Comment: Fixed it for me, but I also add to add the following to the params for a single file upload `public async Task<ActionResult> upload([FromForm(Name="uploadedFileName")]IFormFile uploadedFileName)`

Answer (score 3):

The [ApiController Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute) was added in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and includes binding source parameter inference.  There is a recent [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/49c653ed0baf829cb91bb51bb575306c9f1ec0fa) to Infer BindingSource.FormFile for IEnumerable which may be related.

Comment: I read that part of the guidance when I upgraded my project from Core 2.0 -> Core 2.1.  So are you saying it is a fault?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you could try [.NET Core 2.1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/.NET-Core-2.1.1-Early-Access-Downloads) and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: [ApiController] check if the ModelState is Valid (else give you a 400 response)