# ASPNetCore API IFormFile returning "invalid input"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an api and i'm trying to upload an image. I tried using swagger & postman.

All i'm getting back is

```
{
    "": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

This is how my code looks like ->

Controller -

```
    [HttpPost("images")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        return await _imageHandler.UploadImage(file);
    }
```

Image Handler -

```
public interface IImageHandler
{
    Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file);
}

public class ImageHandler : IImageHandler
{
    private readonly IImageWriter _imageWriter;
    public ImageHandler(IImageWriter imageWriter)
    {
        _imageWriter = imageWriter;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        var result = await _imageWriter.UploadImage(file);
        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
}
```

And finally image writer

```
public class WriterHelper
{
    public enum ImageFormat
    {
        bmp,
        jpeg,
        gif,
        tiff,
        png,
        unknown
    }

    public static ImageFormat GetImageFormat(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var bmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BM");     // BMP
        var gif = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GIF");    // GIF
        var png = new byte[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 };              // PNG
        var tiff = new byte[] { 73, 73, 42 };                  // TIFF
        var tiff2 = new byte[] { 77, 77, 42 };                 // TIFF
        var jpeg = new byte[] { 255, 216, 255, 224 };          // jpeg
        var jpeg2 = new byte[] { 255, 216, 255, 225 };         // jpeg canon

        if (bmp.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(bmp.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.bmp;

        if (gif.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(gif.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.gif;

        if (png.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(png.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.png;

        if (tiff.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(tiff.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.tiff;

        if (tiff2.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(tiff2.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.tiff;

        if (jpeg.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(jpeg.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.jpeg;

        if (jpeg2.SequenceEqual(bytes.Take(jpeg2.Length)))
            return ImageFormat.jpeg;

        return ImageFormat.unknown;
    }
}
```

I was following this tutorial -> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1256591/Upload-Image-to-NET-Core-2-1-API

I've already modified Swagger in the project to be able to upload files, but even swagger throws the same error.
I got no other errors in my code & debugging does nothing (trying to set breakpoints in my controller, but apparently they dont take or they aren't supposed to, still learning here).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Did a clean test and the problem seems to be in `[ApiController]`. Any idea why/how i can fix it?

Comment: Did you choose form-data in postman and type=file?

Comment: @Baral Yes of course, otherwise i wouldnt have been able to test it properly.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895523/asp-core-webapi-test-file-upload-using-postman

Comment: The thing is i put a breakpoint on my controllers return and it doesnt even stop so im guessing it throws the "invalid input" error before even trying to go to my ImageHandler. I just tried adding a return BadRequest(ModelState) with a mock model just to see what i get back and its the same...invalid input.

Comment: My guess is that it could not find a valid route to your API. If you look at the link in my previous comment, it looks like you need to pass a list a IFormFile (IList<IFormFile>)

Comment: Tried everything on there, same result. I even tried the code that seems to have solved his problem. Is there something that i must add to my application to be able to handle file uploading and such? (something that wasnt covered in the tutorial i have followed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180832/discussion-between-baral-and-dante-r).

Comment: Share us postman screen shot. I made a test with [FileController](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/f8d0c911a4218323fe1f20e08104f89bc41fefe7/MVCPro/Controllers/FileController.cs#L12) and [PostMan](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hjnc9wj6PdkK7WB0). **Note**, there is no headers in the postman.

Comment: I added Postman pic. In my headers there's only "Auth Bearer token"

Comment: It was a typo, still not working (it doesnt work in swagger either).

Comment: I've just set up a very basic project that has a single controller accepting a file-upload from Postman and it works without issue - If your controller isn't even being hit, there's likely something happening that's not apparent in your question. If it's practical, you might want to consider boiling this down to a [mcve] and/or pushing something up to e.g. Github that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The thing is i can see "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "UploadImage", controller = "Blog"}. Executing action WebApi.Controllers.BlogController.UploadImage (WebApi)" So it looks like its getting executed. But i can't even debug it (never gets to the return code from that controller method). I have no idea what [mcve] is unfortunately & i wouldnt know what to push to github to be honest. The code above is all i added for the upload. I think i'll try creating a separate controller for it..

Comment: Found the problem. Its apparently because of [ApiController] that i have in my BlogController. Any way around it ?

Comment: Wow! This hapenning to me right now.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 2.0 or 2.1? Your tag says 2.0 but `ApiController` was added in 2.1. Anyway, I think you'll fix it if you follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute) for setting the compatibility version.

Comment: @DanteR. Removing [ApiController] works! To give you all an idea.. I'm trying to make file upload button in Swagger works. This solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @hubert17 See what Kirk linked. Just found another stackoverflow question that seems to have fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919430/post-actions-in-apicontroller-in-asp-net-core-2-1

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my problem and found my fix. 
After finding that my problem was [ApiController] i stumbled upon another stackoverflow problem related to this.

This fixed my problem. Modifying`services.AddMvc()` to -> `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`